# Scan ports from remote hosts

Tags: linux, bash

I'm facing some issues with scanning ports on remote hosts. I've got a list of machines that looks like below:

`10.134.71.197:169.50.114.1:4730`

Which stands for:
remote_host:destination:port

I've tried to solve this using Ansible inventory file, but it might be an overkill.
I was thinking of some bash one-liner who looks like this:

```
for i in `cat list`; do echo $i >> output_file; ssh $i@remote_host "nc -zv destination port" >> output_file; done
```

However I'm still getting output from the localhost instead of the remote server:

```
[user@server dir]$ for i in `cat list`; do echo $i >> output_file; ssh root@$i "nc -zv 169.50.114.1 4730" >> output_file; done

Ncat: Version 7.50 ( https://nmap.org/ncat )
Ncat: Connected to 169.50.114.1:4730.
Ncat: 0 bytes sent, 0 bytes received in 0.03 seconds.

[user@server dir]$ cat output_file

10.134.71.197
```

What is the most efficient way of solving this task?

Answer (score 0):

The `ssh`'s output is print into stderr, therefore, you also need to redirect stderr to a file

```
for i in cat list; do echo $i >> output_file; ssh root@$i "nc -zv 169.50.114.1 4730" >> output_file 2>&1; done
```